# if condition not working in javascript when comparing

Tags: javascript, arrays

i am tryn to loop through a word and check if a perticuler letter exists in it or not but for some reason the condition in if statement is not working.

```
Main.UpdateLetter = function(letter) {
    Main.Changes = 0;

    for(i = 0 ; i < Main.word.length ; i++){

        Main.wordArray[i] = Main.word.charAt(i);

        console.log(Main.wordArray[i]); 

        if (  Main.wordArray[i]  ==  d ) {
            alert("found letter");
        } else {
            console.log("not found");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and clean up your indentation.

Comment: What is`d`? How do you initialize it?

Comment: I suspect you want to compare `Main.wordArray[i]  ===  letter` to use the function argument...

Answer (score 2):

Why are you doing this with this way Java Script has provided you many options, you can do it by using either JavaScript String includes() or indexOf() Method

**includes() Method**

```
var str = "Hello world, welcome to the universe.";
var n = str.includes("world");
```

The result of n will be:**true**
The includes() method determines whether a string contains the characters of a specified string.

This method returns true if the string contains the characters, and false if not.

**indexOf() Method**

```
var str = "Hello world, welcome to the universe.";
var n = str.indexOf("welcome");
```

The result of n will be:**13**
The indexOf() method returns the position of the first occurrence of a specified value in a string.

This method returns -1 if the value to search for never occurs.

Comment: thanks for the help but i'm tryn to figure out what is wrong with the code here....

Comment: in your code you are trying to match a character d, to match a character write like "d" because d is used like a variable

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your trying to do it in a complex way.
Try IndexOf function. 
This method returns the position of the first occurrence of a specified value in a string.
This method returns -1 if the value to search for never occurs
For example:

```
var x = Main.word.indexOf("d");
if( x > -1 ){
    alert("found letter at position "+x);
}
else{
    alert("Letter not found");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want!

```
 for (var i = 0, len = Main.word.length; i < len; i++) {
      if(Main.word.charAt(i) == "A"){
         alert("found letter");
      }else{
         console.log("not found");
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

it is hard to figure out what are you trying to do, I suspect you are trying to use OOP approach to either find if a letter is present in some string or perpaps the method name `UpdateLetter` means you want to replace the letter with some other string...

here is a sample implementation how it can be achieved using prototypical inheritance [constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain#With_a_constructor) and [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method:

```js
// object type definition (sometimes called "class")
function Main (word) {
  this.word = word;
};
Main.prototype.wordHasLetter = function(letter) {
  return this.word.indexOf(letter) !== -1;
};
Main.prototype.replaceLetterInWord = function(letter, replacement) {
  var regex = new RegExp(letter, "g");
  this.word = this.word.replace(regex, replacement);
};

// create instance of the type Main
var main = new Main("abcabc");

// sample usage of the methods
console.log("main.word is:", main.word)
if (main.wordHasLetter("a")) {
  console.log("found letter")
} else {
  console.log("not found")
}
main.replaceLetterInWord("a", "x");
console.log(main.word);
```